# Type Conversion error in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Heres a bitmap image saving code snippet in vb.net. Can somebody please help me understand why am I getting an error here stating that i am trying to convert string to double while saving the image. how to correct that?

```
Private Sub Timer5_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer5.Tick
            x = MyRandomNumber.Next(1000)
            screenWidth = Screen.GetBounds(New Point(0, 0)).Width
            screenHeight = Screen.GetBounds(New Point(0, 0)).Height
            Dim bmpScreenShot As New Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight)
            Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenShot)
            gfx.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, New Size(screenWidth, screenHeight))
        ***bmpScreenShot.Save("D:\\screenshots\\" + x + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)***
    End Sub
```

Comment: After you've fixed the conversion issue, you'll probably want to change the double slashes ` \\ ` into single slashes ` \ `... as double ones are only needed in C#, and not VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

`"D:\\screenshots\\"` is as string. `x` is a double.

You try to add `"D:\\screenshots\\"` and `x`, and this fails, because `"D:\\screenshots\\"` is not a double.

That's what the compiler tries to tell you.

---

Have a look at the documentation of the [`+` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9c5t70w2.aspx):

> In general, + performs arithmetic addition when possible, and concatenates only when both expressions are strings.
>
> **Data types of expressions:**
>
> Object expression holds a numeric value and the other is of type String
>
> **Action by compiler:**
>
> If Option Strict is On, then generate a compiler error.
>
> If Option Strict is Off, then implicitly convert the String to Double and add.
>
> If the String cannot be converted to Double, then throw an InvalidCastException exception.

---

To concatenate strings use the [`&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wfx50zyk.aspx):

> Generates a string concatenation of two expressions.

```
... "D:\\screenshots\\" & x & ".jpg"...
```

or `String.Format`:

```
String.Format("D:\\screenshots\\{0}.jpg", x)
```

---

**Lesson learned:**

Always use `Option Strict On`, and always look up the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
bmpScreenShot.Save("D:\\screenshots\\" + x.ToString() + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use & instead of + to concatenate the path:

```
bmpScreenShot.Save("D:\\screenshots\\" & x & ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```